# Add elements to array which has gapped numeric keys to form an indexed array / list

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, key, default-value

I have an array like this:

```
$array = [
    0 => 'Apple',
    2 => 'Orange',
    5 => 'Pear',
    8 => 'Pear'
]
```

Is there a way to fill in the missing indexes with a default value (for example, an empty string or `null`)?

I'd like to insert new elements into the array at the following keys: `1`, `3`, `4`, `6`, `7`

My result should be:

```
[
    0 => 'Apple',
    1 => '',
    2 => 'Orange',
    3 => '',
    4 => '',
    5 => 'Pear',
    6 => '',
    7 => '',
    8 => 'Pear'
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be faster for larger arrays. For smaller arrays any method will do.

```
$existingKeys = array_keys($array);

//you can use any value instead of null
$newKeys = array_fill_keys(range(min($existingKeys), max($existingKeys)), null);
$array += $newKeys;

//optional, probably not needed
ksort($array);
```

Comment: `ksort()` absolutely IS required if the array is to become an indexed list; otherwise the new keys will simply be appended after the originals.  `array_fill_keys()` is the long way around for this task -- filling an array with all indexes from zero to the highest numeric key can be simply done with `array_fill()`. This answer is using more function calls than it needs to.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73758887/2943403).

Answer (score 2):

```
for($i=0;i<count($array);++$i){
    $array[$i] = isset($array[$i])? $array[$i] : '';
}
```

It just fills the missing keys with an empty string, though. Not sure if this suits you.

**Edit**

Just noticed Perr0_hunter wrote pretty much the same thing before I did :P

Comment: In my opinion, this answer is deceptively correct.  https://3v4l.org/DnMiM  At first glance, it should be unreliable because the input array has 4 elements (`count($array) === 4`), yet the array needs 5 new elements to be generated.  The trick (inefficiency) in this answer (that perrohunter's answer does not correct) is that after every iteration, the `for()` loop's 2nd parameter is recalculating the modified input's length.  In other words, the `count()` keeps increasing until it doesn't need to anymore. I should also, note that the new keys are simply appended, so a `ksort()` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

you could try a for() from the lowest index to the highest and complete if it's empty

```
for($i = 0 ;$i <= 8 ; $i++) 
{
//if it's not set
if(!isset($array[$i]))
{
//set to empty
$array[$i] = "";
}

}
```

Additionally you could count first the number of elements on the array and wrap it in a function

```
 function completeIndexes($array)
    {

    $total = count($array);
     for($i = 0 ;$i < $total ; $i++) 

        {
        //if it's not set
        if(!isset($array[$i]))
        {
        //set to empty
        $array[$i] = "";
        }

        }
return $array; 
    }
```

Comment: This answer is provably very incorrect: https://3v4l.org/hjeT3

Answer (score 0):

Sensibly, you can use a manual loop from 0 to the last numeric key and populate a new array.  (Of course, if the array keys are not already sorted in an ascending fashion, you will need to isolate the `max()` `array_key()` to find the final key of the newly formed array.)

Or you can use a functional approach to overwrite a default-value-filled, temporary array with the input array's data.

Here are two valid approaches: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mtO3q))

```
$result = [];
for (
    $i = 0, $last = array_key_last($array);
    $i <= $last;
    ++$i
) {
    $result[$i] = $array[$i] ?? null;
}
var_export($result);
```

And

```
var_export(
    array_replace(
        array_fill(0, array_key_last($array), null),
        $array
    )
);
```

---

p.s. Note that `array_merge()` and the "array union operator" (`+`) are not suitable techniques to join the default array with the original array -- or at best, the union operator needs to be followed by a `ksort()` call.

Demo of technique that I do NOT endorse: https://3v4l.org/lCS0n

Answer (score -2):

If what you're trying to do is reorder the array so you get

```
Array( [0] => Apple [1] => Orange [2] => Pear [3] => Pear )
```

Just create a new Array and copy the values into it. It will allocate new indexes sequentially

i.e.

```
$new_array = array();
for( $value in $old_array )
  $new_array[] = $value;
```

Comment: use array_Values() instead of your for loop

Comment: This answer does not implement valid PHP code. https://3v4l.org/P2eNv